# In der Stimmung sein

Tags: subordinate-clause, inflection

Wie kann ich diesen Satz im Futur sagen?

> Ich weiß es nicht, ob ich in der Stimmung werde.

Comment: Was sagt denn das Wörterbuch zum Futur? "In der Stimmung sein" ist übrigens kein Satz.

Comment: Please note that you can use the present tense as well, see https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4015/when-to-use-the-future-tense for more. In colloquial speech it is even prefered.

Comment: Dieser Satz ist nicht verständlich. Ist "in der Stimmung *sein*" gemeint? Dann ist das Futur ganz regelmäßig "...in der Stimmung sein werde".

Answer (score 9):

### Flexion des unregelmäßigen Verbs *»sein«*

- Präsens:

  > Ich **bin** daheim. Ich **bin** Zuckerbäcker. Ich **bin** in der Stimmung.
- Präteritum:

  > Ich **war** daheim. Ich **war** Zuckerbäcker. Ich **war** in der Stimmung.
- Perfekt:

  > Ich **bin** daheim **gewesen**. Ich **bin** Zuckerbäcker **gewesen**. Ich **bin** in der Stimmung **gewesen**.
- Plusquamperfekt:

  > Ich **war** daheim **gewesen**. Ich **war** Zuckerbäcker **gewesen**. Ich **war** in der Stimmung **gewesen**.
- Futur I:

  > Ich **werde** daheim **sein**. Ich **werde** Zuckerbäcker **sein**. Ich **werde** in der Stimmung **sein**.
- Futur II:

  > Ich **werde** daheim **gewesen sein**. Ich **werde** Zuckerbäcker **gewesen sein**. Ich **werde** in der Stimmung **gewesen sein**.

---

### Position des Verbs in einem Nebensatz

In Hauptsätzen steht bei mehrteiligen Verben das infinite Verb immer an Position 2 des Satzes, alle anderen Teile des Verbs stehen am Ende. (Siehe Beispiele oben)

In Nebensätzen steht das infinite Verb aber ganz am Ende:

> Ich **bin** daheim.
>   Ich weiß nicht, ob *ich daheim **bin***.
>
> Ich **werde** daheim **gewesen sein**.
>   Ich weiß nicht, ob *ich daheim **gewesen sein werde***.

---

### Lösung

Da dein Satz Futur I verwendet, und der fragliche Teil in einem Nebensatz vorkommt, lautet er richtig:

> Ich weiß es nicht, ob *ich in der Stimmung **sein werde***.

---

### Verbesserungsvorschläge

Das Wort *»es«* im Hauptsatz ist zwar nicht falsch, aber überflüssig, weil der Nebensatz als Ganzes die Rolle des Objekts im Hauptsatz einnimmt, und man das Wort *»es«* daher nicht mehr benötigt:

> Ich weiß nicht, ob ich in der Stimmung sein werde.

Noch ein Verbesserungsvorschlag:

Die Phrase *»in Stimmung sein«* (ohne Artikel vor *Stimmung*) wird häufiger verwendet als *»in der Stimmung sein«* (mit Artikel). Aber das hängt auch sehr vom Kontext ab. Du wirst also von allen Varianten am ehesten diesen Satz von einem Muttersprachler hören:

> Ich weiß nicht, ob ich in Stimmung sein werde.

Comment: +1 for the amazing level of detail!

Answer (score 4):

German speakers use the *Futur I* sparsely. The sentence

> Ich weiß (es) nicht, ob ich in der Stimmung **sein werde**.

is correct but it sounds incredibly awkward to me. Much better:

> Ich weiß (es) nicht, ob ich **dann** in der Stimmung **bin**.

If you want to sound natural, use the simple present and markers as *dann*, *später* or *irgendwann*.

Comment: The answer by Hubert Schölnast about the grammar of *sein* is detailed and correct. However, in colloquial language, I'd most likely use the structure Janka suggests, as it feels more natural.